# Why is 'terraform apply' ignoring previous 'terraform import' of S3 bucket resulting in a BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Here's my Terraform code:

**s3.tf**

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "prod_media" {
  bucket = var.prod_media_bucket
  force_destroy = true
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_cors_configuration" "prod_media" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.prod_media.id  

  cors_rule {
    allowed_headers = ["*"]
    allowed_methods = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    allowed_origins = ["*"]
    expose_headers  = ["ETag"]
    max_age_seconds = 3000
  }  
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "prod_media" {
    bucket = aws_s3_bucket.prod_media.id
    acl    = "public-read"
    depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls.s3_bucket_acl_ownership]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "s3_bucket_acl_ownership" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.prod_media.id
  rule {
    object_ownership = "BucketOwnerPreferred"
  }
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.example]
}

resource "aws_iam_user" "prod_media_bucket" {
  name = "prod-media-bucket"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "example" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.prod_media.id

  block_public_acls       = false
  block_public_policy     = false
  ignore_public_acls      = false
  restrict_public_buckets = false
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "prod_media_bucket" {
    bucket = aws_s3_bucket.prod_media.id
    policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Principal = "*"
        Action = [
          "s3:*",
        ]
        Effect = "Allow"
        Resource = [
          "arn:aws:s3:::${var.prod_media_bucket}",
          "arn:aws:s3:::${var.prod_media_bucket}/*"
        ]
      },
      {
        Sid = "PublicReadGetObject"
        Principal = "*"
        Action = [
          "s3:GetObject",
        ]
        Effect   = "Allow"
        Resource = [
          "arn:aws:s3:::${var.prod_media_bucket}",
          "arn:aws:s3:::${var.prod_media_bucket}/*"
        ]
      },
    ]
  })
  
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.example]
}

resource "aws_iam_access_key" "prod_media_bucket" {
  user = aws_iam_user.prod_media_bucket.name
}
```

**variables.tf** (part of it)

```
variable "prod_media_bucket" {
  description = "S3 Bucket for production media files"
  default = "prod-media-8675309"
}
```

The bucket already exists, I can view it in my AWS Console.

I even use the bucket for my Terraform state.
**provider.tf** (some of it):

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "prod-media-8675309"
    key    = "terraform"
    region = "us-east-2"
  }
}
```

I have tried the `terrarform import` command as follows:

```bash
terraform import aws_s3_bucket.prod_media prod-media-8675309
terraform plan
terraform apply
```

The import has this result (which I think is successful):
[image]

However I keep getting this *BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou* error.  Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: Did the import command work?

Comment: Yes, it was successful

Comment: Can you do `terraform state list` and check if the state file is aware of the bucket?

Comment: terraform state list does not return anything.

Comment: Is there a `terraform.tfstate` file in the same directory or are you using remote state?

Comment: I updated the question a bit with more content.  I still have the old **terraform.tfstate** file locally (last updated 3 days ago), but I now use a remote state (same S3 bucket that I'm having trouble with)

Comment: The screenshot shows only the import was prepared, not it was completed successfully.

Comment: Why would want the S3 bucket to be within this specific terraform state file and then also store the state file within that bucket?